# Android notification: the top notification is not expanded

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

According to the code below, I create a notification which is expandable.
    private void bannerNotif() {
        Notification foregroundNote;
        RemoteViews bigView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageName(), R.layout.banner_notif);

```
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.featuredimagehandler);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this);
    foregroundNote = mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Description")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon).setLargeIcon(icon).build();

    foregroundNote.bigContentView = bigView;
    NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyManager.notify(2, foregroundNote);
}
```

According to this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

> A notification's big view appears only when the notification is expanded, which happens when the notification is at the top of the notification drawer, or when the user expands the notification with a gesture.

the problem is when this notification is placed on top, it is not expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the issue was that the layout I created for the notification had a height of "MATCH_PARENT" so it was too big to fit. Setting the height to a reasonable value solved the issue and the notification expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I also had something similar with remoteviews and notifications. Mine ended up not expanding because my notification_id was not unique throughout my app :)